# output specific data from div and print it via printer

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, html

I've spent all day in getting a solution for my need but since i'm not an experienced coder it's time for me to ask you guys for a little help.

My scenario is:
I have some php code like:

```
<div id="unique_name">
<?php function_show_qrcode()?>
<?php function_show_text1()?>
<?php function_show_text2()?>
<?php function_show_text3()?>
</div>
```

What i want to achieve is to print the content of "unique_name" div (qrcode and some additional info) directly to a label printer attached via wireless on my smartphone and PC, printer that prints on continuous paper with a width of 62mm.

I have tried a lot of codes that i found but with no success because of browsers behavior regarding window.print()

The following code is working on firefox and chrome on pc but it is not working on safari mobile

```
<script>
        function printDiv(unique_name) {
        var printContents = document.getElementById(unique_name).innerHTML;
        var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
        document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
        window.print();
        document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
            }
</script>

<a href="#" rel="nofollow" onclick="printDiv('unique_name')">Print label</a>
```

I am stuck on that and i think that something like converting the content of unique_name div into an image, save it and print it after that should work but there are a lot of steps to do and we want to do it more easy something like click and print or click and popup and then print and the most important thing is that it needs to work on mobile browsers

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
<script>
function printDiv(myId){

    var HiddenElements = document.querySelectorAll( 'body *' ); // get all the elements in the body
    var VisibleElements = document.querySelectorAll( '#' + myId + ' *' ); // gets the elements inside the div to be printed

    var index = 0, length = HiddenElements.length;
    for (  ; index < length; index++) {
        HiddenElements[index].style.visibility = "hidden"; // hide all the elements in the body             
    }   

    index = 0;
    length = VisibleElements.length;
    for (  ; index < length; index++) {
        VisibleElements[index].style.visibility = "visible"; // show all the elements inside the div to be printed      
    }

    // display the element to be printed

    myElement = document.getElementById(myId);
    myElement.style.visibility = "visible"

    var oldPos = myElement.style.position;
    myElement.style.position = "absolute";
    myElement.style.left = 0;
    myElement.style.top = 0;

    setTimeout(window.print, 1000); // Wait a bit for the DOM then Print ( Safari :/ )

    // wait for the data to be sent to the printer then display the previous content
    setTimeout(function(){      
        index = 0;
        length = HiddenElements.length;
        for (  ; index < length; index++) {
            HiddenElements[index].style.visibility = "visible";             
        }   

        myElement.style.position = oldPos;

    }, 5000);

}
</script>

<a href="#" rel="nofollow" onclick="printDiv('unique_name')">Print label</a>
```

JsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/2m5ha1ta/67/

i don't know why on JsFiddle the `onclick` doesn't work, so i added an `id` to the `a` and added an `eventListener` to it and it's working ( check the fiddle )

Comment: @Gino sorry there was some typos, i edited the answer and the Fiddle. (  https://jsfiddle.net/2m5ha1ta/65/ )

Comment: my friend u made my day better :) Thank you very much for your help! One more thing if it is possible. I want that after clicking and send the div (label) to the printer to stay/return on same page.

Comment: youère welcome, ièm glad i could help, there you go https://jsfiddle.net/2m5ha1ta/67/

Comment: Hello again my friend :) i've finished putting all together and now i noticed one thing that we missed both of us. The code is working as expected all good for now but the problem came when printing because the code is getting all the page, hide all elements except the one that we need and in that case there is a lot of blank space. Can we take only that div something like 234x234 pixels and nothing else from that page?

Answer (score 0):

i don't know why exactly but apparently in `Safari` , `Window.print` is executed before the DOM is manipulated, 
try putting the `window.print()` in a `timeout`:

replace this line `window.print();` with `setTimeout(window.print, 1000);`

give it some time to print, then put back the original content :)

```
setTimeout(function(){
    document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}, 2000)
```

you can play with the timeout's number of milliseconds until you get the sweet spot, it doesn't have to be 2000.

Comment: thank you for your response but it is not working. The same behavior when printing it gets the whole page not only the selected div

Comment: @Gino , oh i see .. i updated my answer, maybe this will help.

Comment: we are close my friend :)

Comment: we are close my friend :) now i have the output needed (the content of div) but after the time i've set up on that function the browser gets back to initial state. Also if i'm trying to print on mobile via airprint safari still gets the entire page

Comment: i'm not sure i understand but i think that at this point you need to take a look at `@media print`  to hide the elements you don't want in the `print` in the `css` , https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/

Comment: @Gino i added another answer, i hope it helps :)

Comment: hello and thak you again, something i'm doing wrong i guess because it is not working. Here u have all the code to work on it.https://jsfiddle.net/2m5ha1ta/54/